# Average number of hops in a hash map

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, formula

I have written an algorithm that implements a hash map to solve a problem. I am wondering if anybody can give me some kind of general formula for calculating the average number of hops to find an entry? Just part of my report :)
I have created my own hash code function, and I am trying to measure the quality of it.

By "hops" I mean:

For collision handling: If two or more element's hashCodes map to the same index in the hash table, I built a "linked list" at that index. So if there are 4 elements that are mapped to an index 'i' in the hash table, then the index 'i' contains a linked list of 4 elements. "Hops" in this sense is "walking" or "hopping" through that linked list.

Essentially, there is another data structure at each index of the map.

Comment: Did you implement a hash map or did you use one?

Comment: Implemented a "custom" version of Java's hash map class.

Comment: Interesting, what did you modify?

Comment: asymptotically it is order of log(n).

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "hop"?  "Hops" makes sense for a tree or a skip list variant, not a hash table.  Collisions in a hash table is more dependant on the hash function, not the implementation of the table (if the table is done properly anyway.)

Comment: @Affe: Of course, sorry.

Comment: Well, if you come up with a way to analytically estimate collisions in an arbitrary hash function, you can probably have your pick of PhD advisors :)  But this is probably a task for an empirical test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be completely explicit, the number of 'hops' along the list in a hashtable which uses lists to handle collisions is identical to the number of hash collisions in the table, which will be the number of times `hash(item) % size of table` evaluates to the same value for the data provided. For hash tables which use the spare slots in the table, colliding items which have been removed from the table also contribute.

For example, if your table size were to increase in whole powers of two but your hash function only had differences in the higher bits, then you would have many collisions in the table even though your external hash has no collisions in its outputs. One technique (IIRC the one used in Sun's implementation) is to use prime numbers as the table size, another is to use a bit-mixing function to process the provided hash function's output before taking the lowest n-bits as the index.

So the number of collisions depends on the spread of values of the provided hash function found in your data ( if they all collide, then the table implementation can't do anything ), on the choice of table size for a given load factor, and how the output of the provided hash is converted to a table index.

Answer (score 1):

The performance will depend on the quality of the hash function as well as the distribution of the data. Pick a large representative data set and measure the performance.

Comment: It also depends on the max. load factor of the hashtable.

Comment: Yes it does. I am looking for a way to calculate the average number of hops when performing a lookup on an element.

Answer (score 1):

> I am calculating my own hashCode, and I am trying to measure the quality of it.

What you need to do is forget about the hash table, and simply analyze the distribution of hash values across the range of the `int` type.  Ideally you want hash values to be distributed uniformly.  Any significant peaks represent potential problems.

The other thing you need to take into account is the distribution of the keys used in your actual application.  For instance, the hash function may hash "similar" keys in a way that doesn't give much dispersion.  If your application then uses lots of similar keys you will end up with lots of collisions.

---

If you try to calculate / estimate / measure the number of "hops", you run into the effect of things like the initial `HashMap` size, the order of key insertion, the effect of resizing and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Take a sample input set S and calculate the hash values for every element in S and insert the calculated value into a set H. |S| / |H| is the average collisions you should expect. This depends on your own hash function, the quality of it.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation of the [Java HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.

In other words, it depends on the quality of the hash function implemented for the items you are storing in it.

Comment: I am calculating my own hashCode, and I am trying to measure the quality of it.